# Get SUM field in Doctrine query

Tags: php, doctrine

How can I get the value of  sum field of a query result?

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('SUM( t.field1)')
                        ->from('table')
                        ->group_bt('t.field2');
```

I've tried something like  `$q->sum` but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misspelled at 4th line which should be -

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('SUM( t.field1) AS sum')
->from('table')
->groupBy('t.field2');
```

$sun_value = $q->sum;

Comment: and how i can use the sum value? now is stored on $q,but if i need to use it? `$sun_value = $q->sum`??or how?